# www.domain.net works but domain.net does not? Apache2 .conf files

Tags: apache2

I have two domains but I'm trying to make them work threw subfolders like `/var/www/html/subfolder1` and `/var/www/html/subfolder2`. I just got it to work but the domain will not go to the same place if I do `www.kofgaming.net` it goes into the [subfolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUZ5v.png) and if do `kofgaming.net` it goes to the [/var/www/html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRVd2.png) folder!

Here is what the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/kofgaming.net.conf`[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/CmwiFZbR).

Also here is the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/e0tLUgqb).

I just want to state I'm new to apache and ubuntu so please bear with me if I didn't make sense any help would be appreciated. If you Need any information from me feel free to ask. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should define two separate Virtual Hosts. They could be defined into a separate configuration files or both could be defined within the same configuration file. Let's assume we want both Virtual Hosts to be defined within the configuration file `000-default.conf`, so (according to [your pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CmwiFZbR)) its content must look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@kofgaming.net

    ServerName kofgaming.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/kofgaming
    <Directory /var/www/html/kofgaming>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@kofgaming.net

    ServerName www.kofgaming.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.kofgaming
    <Directory /var/www/html/www.kofgaming>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after changing of the configuration.